# Align multicolumn in .text

Tags: tables, luatex, xtable

I want to align values in the green box to the left and need some suggestions for the line spacing [image: table]. many thank in advance,

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|ccccccc}  
        \toprule
        % & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Variable}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1} \\ \midrule   
        & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Factor} \\     \midrule
        Variable &&& 0 &&& 1  \\ \midrule 
        Gender && Female & 21.27\% && Male & 78.73\% \\ 
        Married && Others & 10.8\% && Married/Cohabited & 89.2\% \\  \midrule
        & \multicolumn{7}{c}{} \\   %\midrule
        && West && East &&Center  \\ \midrule 
        Region  &&  27.7\%  && 41.1\%  && 30.2\%  \\ \midrule
        & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Continuous} \\     \midrule     %& \multicolumn{3}{c}{RF}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{GBM}\\   \midrule        
        &     Mean   &      SD &   Median &        Min   &   Max & Skew & Kurt \\ \midrule 
        Income &  77263.25  &197349.48  &45575.00      &109.00  &5000000 &16.30   &347.98 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
    \caption{Sample description.}
    \label{tab:Sample-Description}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The table appears to be a collection of disparate things that are arranged in 2 (gender; marital status; or maybe 2x2?), 3 (region), and 7 (income) data columns. Is this impression correct? Is there any kind of hierachy among the variables?

Comment: I want to show continues and 2-3 level factor variables differently, for the same dataset

Comment: The information you're looking to convey would appear to be rather ill-suited for display in a table format. E.g., what's the connection between "female", "others", 'west", and "sd", or between "male", "married", and "max"? Trying to display such disparate items in a table is bound to confuse, rather than to enlighten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This table design is hard of understand as Mico commented, but also is hard to implement as there are rows with 4, 5, 8 of cells of different widths, so it cannot be solved with  simply merging some cells.

I think that the best solution is split this in three different tables,  or redesign completely the table, or not use a table but a list or something else. Said that, this is an attempt  to make it clearer, using `tabularx` and nested tabularx:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\arraybackslash\centering}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Sample description.}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{2cm}XcXc}  
        \toprule
   Variable   &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Factor} \\\cmidrule(rl){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-5}    
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1}  \\ 
        \cmidrule(rl){2-3}\cmidrule(rl){4-5} 
        Gender & Female \dotfill & 21.27 \% & Male \dotfill & 78.73 \% \\ 
        Married & Others \dotfill & 10.80 \% & Married/Cohabited \dotfill & 89.20 \% \\\addlinespace[1em]
Region & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}{zzz}  
West & East & Center \tabularnewline
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3} 
27.7 \%  & 41.1 \%  & 30.2 \% \tabularnewline\end{tabularx}}
\\\addlinespace[1em]
Income & \multicolumn{4}{c}{%\small%
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}{zzzzzzz}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{\normalsize Continuous}\tabularnewline\midrule
Mean & SD & Median & Min &  Max & Skew & Kurt \tabularnewline\midrule 
77263.25  &197349.48  &45575.00  &109.00  &5000000 &16.30   &347.98 \tabularnewline\addlinespace[1em] 
\end{tabularx}  
}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, Fran.