# alignment in multicolumn

Tags: tables, luatex, xtable

taking the code from [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577262/align-multicolumn-in-text/577598#577598) and [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577625/add-a-line-in-multicolumn/577629#577629) but I can not fit it to the page properly [image].

```
 \documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcolumntype{z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Sample description.}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{2.5cm}XcXc@{}}
\toprule
Variable   &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Factor} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){2-5}    
           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1}  \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}

Gender   & Female \dotfill & 21.27 \% & Male \dotfill & 78.73 \% \\
Married  & Others \dotfill & 10.80 \% & Married/Cohabited \dotfill & 89.20 \% \\
Employed & Others \dotfill & 34.02\%  &  Employed \dotfill & 65.98\% \\
Education & Others  \dotfill & 80.79\% & High-school or above \dotfill & 19.21\% \\
Party & Others      \dotfill & 81.89\% & Party       \dotfill & 18.11\% \\
HR    & Rural       \dotfill & 58.5\%  & Urban       \dotfill& 41.5\% \\
Access Loan & Others\dotfill & 73.69\% & Access Loan \dotfill & 26.31\% \\
Formal & Others     \dotfill & 91.95\% & Formal      \dotfill & 8.05\% \\
Informal & Others   \dotfill & 85.26\% & Informal    \dotfill & 14.74\% \\
Both & Others       \dotfill & 96.48\% & Both        \dotfill & 3.52\% \\
No Loans & Others   \dotfill & 26.31\% & No loans    \dotfill& 73.69\% \\ %\addlinespace[1em]

\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1ex}

\makebox[\dimexpr 2.5cm+2.5\tabcolsep][l]{Region}%
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm-2.5\tabcolsep}{@{}zzz@{}}
West & East & Center \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(rl){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
27.7 \%  & 41.1 \%  & 30.2 \%
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1ex}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{}p{\dimexpr 2.5cm+\tabcolsep}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{7}{c}@{}}
& \multicolumn{7}{c}{\normalsize Continuous}\\
\cmidrule{2-8}
& Mean & SD & Median & Min &  Max & Skew & Kurt \\
\cmidrule{2-8}
Age    &     54.38      &13.39     &53.00       &18.00      &101  &0.12   & -0.47 \\
Income &  77263.25  &197349.48  &45575.00      &109.00  &5000000 &16.30   &347.98 \\
Networth & 836411.01 &1656146.88 &330972.64 &-3387183.98 &19941804  &5.76   & 47.37 \\
NW-HE & 254640.44 &1054721.27  &24363.09 &-5328515.56 &19747761 &10.01   &138.76 \\
Liquid Assets & 935052.61 &1744912.48 &405922.47     &1257.82 &20000000  &5.76   & 47.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` right before the last `\begin{tabular*}` should work. Alternatively, you could also decrease the font size in all tables, for example by adding `\small` before the first `\begin{tabularx}`.

Comment: Entirely unrelated, but sometimes thare is a space between the number and the % inside of the first tabularx, sometimes there is no space. You might want to unify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best option is to use three separate `tabular` or `tabularx` environments.

I would also align the numbers in the data columns on their respective decimal separators.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=0.5em}X}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[group-digits=false]{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Sample description.}
\centering

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} X XrXr @{}}
\toprule
\addlinespace
&  \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Factor} \\
 \cmidrule(l){2-5}    
Variable & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{1}  \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}

Gender   & Female \dotfill & 21.27\%   & Male \dotfill        & 78.73\% \\
Married  & Others \dotfill & 10.80\%   & Married/Cohabited \dotfill & 89.20\% \\
Employed & Others \dotfill & 34.02\%   &  Employed \dotfill   & 65.98\% \\
Education & Others  \dotfill & 80.79\% & High-school or above \dotfill & 19.21\% \\
Party     & Others  \dotfill & 81.89\% & Party       \dotfill & 18.11\% \\
HR        & Rural   \dotfill & 58.50\% & Urban       \dotfill & 41.50\% \\
Access Loan & Others\dotfill & 73.69\% & Access Loan \dotfill & 26.31\% \\
Formal   & Others   \dotfill & 91.95\% & Formal      \dotfill & 8.05\% \\
Informal & Others   \dotfill & 85.26\% & Informal    \dotfill & 14.74\% \\
Both     & Others   \dotfill & 96.48\% & Both        \dotfill & 3.52\% \\
No Loans & Others   \dotfill & 26.31\% & No loans    \dotfill & 73.69\% 
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{3.5ex}

\begin{tabular}{@{} lccc @{}}
& West & East & Center \\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
Region & 27.7\%  & 41.1\%  & 30.2\%
\end{tabular}

\vspace{3ex}

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L T{6.2} T{7.2} T{6.2} T{-7.2} T{8.0} T{2.2} T{3.2} @{} }
& \multicolumn{7}{c@{}}{Continuous}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
& {Mean} & {SD} & {Median} & {Min} &  {Max} & {Skew} & {Kurt} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
Age    &     54.38      &13.39     &53.00       &18.00      &101  &0.12   & -0.47 \\
Income &  77263.25  &197349.48  &45575.00      &109.00  &5000000 &16.30   &347.98 \\
Net worth& 836411.01 &1656146.88 &330972.64 &-3387183.98 &19941804  &5.76   & 47.37 \\
NW-HE & 254640.44 &1054721.27  &24363.09 &-5328515.56 &19747761 &10.01   &138.76 \\
Liquid Assets & 935052.61 &1744912.48 &405922.47 &1257.82 &20000000  &5.76   & 47.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't help but observe that the middle `tabular` environment is not at all clear. Aren't "West", "Center", and "East" also regions? Thus, why is the label "Region" affixed to the first row. Shouldn't the label be something like "Share" or "Percentage Share", especially as the numbers would add up to (close to) 100%?